# Is there 3D Viewer for the Wikitude SDK that doesn't require wt3 file conversion?

Tags: cordova, wikitude

Does the Wikitude SDK 7.X - 8.X offer a 3D Viewer option for the immediate display of FBX or OBJ files from services like SketchFab, Google Poly, or SVRF without first converting to wt3 files?  We have a requirement to display 3D objects from 3rd Party services.  We're finding that these services use ARKit and ARCore or Unity with importers that immediately display 3D Objects.

We use a Cordova and Ionic implementation with the Wikitude SDK.  Let me know if you have additional questions.

Thanks,

-John